# Calling Secure Web Service from Anonymous web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have a web service that is set as secure via the web config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />    
<authorization>
  <allow roles="MET\Web-Admin"/>     
  <deny users="*"/>
  <allow users="MET\JoeUser;MET\JoeSmith"/>
</authorization>
```

And also in IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008) it has the following set for Authentication:

```
Anonymous Authentication:Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation:   Disabled
Basic Authentication     Disabled
Forms Authentication:    Disabled
Windows Authentication:  Enabled
```

The anonymous site I am calling it from in IIS7 is:

```
Anonymous Authentication:Enabled
ASP.NET Impersonation:   Disabled
Basic Authentication     Disabled
Forms Authentication:    Enabled
Windows Authentication:  Disabled
```

In the Anonymous web site, I call the secure web service via:

```
moms.momService myMom = new moms.momService();
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password");            
strStatus = myMom.createBackupDirectoryAndPrivs(sData);
```

Everytime I run this, it returns as Unauthorized.  I have made sure this user is in the Web-Admin AD Group.  I also tried adding the user as an *Allow User* but still unauthorized.  I am pretty sure the problem lies somewhere in IIS but not sure what else to check.

BTW:  For what it's worth, if I run the Anonymous site via VS2010 development on my dev box, and call the secure site using above code, it works fine.  This is why I am thinking IIS on the PROD server.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Geo...

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the deny setting after the allow settings since they are processed in order from top to bottom:

```
<allow roles="MET\Web-Admin"/>     
<allow users="MET\JoeUser;MET\JoeSmith"/>
<deny users="*"/>
```